# How to lock firefox version?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

I would like to lock firefox version in ubuntu 10.10 as we are running our software in firefox version 3.6. Coz of this we are unable to upgrade the latest packages and updates if i do that firefox version is also getting updated to version 10. I just want to lock the firefox version so that it wont be updated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can lock a version by following these simple steps:

1. Open a terminal
2. `sudo -s` and hit enter
3. Enter your password for sudo
4. `echo firefox hold | dpkg --set-selections`

This will lock (aka pin) the 'firefox' package.

To remove the lock replace step 4 with `echo firefox install | dpkg --set-selections`.

If you prefer a GUI then you can open *Synaptic Package Manager*, choose the package and from menu select *Package->Lock Version*.